# Stumped: NSURLConnection + php - key/value format issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm stumped. Trying to post to a php script with NSURLConnection. Been at this all afternoon so I figured it's time to ask for help. I've read through lots of the posts here @ NSURLConnection but I still haven't figured out my error.

I'm uploading an image, with two key/value pairs: `userfile` and `user`. The ObjC code I'm using is below. Log output shows the string (skipping the image data). I used the php script at the bottom for testing my server side php in the browser: it works fine. So I am screwing up in the ObjC code somehow.

Anyone see where I am going wrong?

//log output

> -----------------------------14737809831466499882746641449
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data;
>
> userfile=someImage&user=sleepy;
>
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream

//objC

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, .5);

NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/loader.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; \r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString * user = @"sleepy";

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"userfile=someImage"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&user=%@;\r\n", user] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString * testOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(testOutput); // log it

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:request
 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"Response: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }];
```

// browser

```
<?php
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$uploadHandler = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'cuploader.php';

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Upload form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <h1>
        Test 
    </h1>
    <p>
        <label for="userfile">File to upload:</label>
        <input id="userfile" type="text" name="userfile">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user">User</label>
        <input id="user" type="text" name="user">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="submit">Press to...</label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!">
    </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function I use to send POST data..

```
    -(void)sendData:(NSString*)data toServer:(NSString*)url{
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn){
    //Connection successful
}
else{
    //Connection Failed
}

[conn release];
```

}

Where the 'data' string is in the form of @"&user=username&pass=password", etc.

For uploading images, I add this:

```
    NSData *jpeg = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
//UIImageJPEGRepresentation
NSString *param = @"";
NSString *footer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n--%@--\n", @"0194784892923"];

param = [param stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\n", @"0194784892923"]];
param = [param stringByAppendingString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"image.png\"\nContent-Type: image/png\n\n"];
//NSLog(@"jpeg size: %d", [jpeg length]);

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
[data appendData:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[data appendData:jpeg];
[data appendData:[[UserInfo retrieveSingleton].userName dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[data appendData:[footer dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Hope this helps.