# Upload photos from iphone to webserver

Tags: php, iphone, ios, upload, webserver

I tried to upload photos from my iPhone App to my [webserver](http://wasnaga.nestons.org/420/), by using many different .php upload scripts, but I've gained no success so far!

Please check my iPhone source code:

```
- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://wasnaga.nestons.org/420/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"------------------------1473780983146499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);   
}
```

There are any error? Can you help me with the .php file?

Comment: Look at the answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746052/stumped-nsurlconnection-php-key-value-format-issue/9747272#9747272

Comment: nothing it still not working i tried also to change code but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a backslash in the first appendData line you have:

```
@"\r\n--%@r\n"
```

It should be:

```
@"\r\n--%@\r\n"
```